# UICollectionViewCell disappears when settings contentOffset

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a `UICollectionView` that slides its items based on a certain trigger. 
I'm trying to animate the cells transition by:

```
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4,
                           delay: 0.5, animations: {

                            self.headingsCollectionView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: x, y: 0)
                            self.headingsCollectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
            })
```

The animation is successful, the problem is when I change the CollectionView contentOffset the current item disappears instead of scrolling off.

- I tried reloading the current item (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41527018/4240041)) so it
  would stay visible but it's still not working.
- I've tried `scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated` but
  it's not animating the item transition.
- setContentOffset:animated Tried it, it doesn't animate as well.

Comment: remove  self.headingsCollectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])

Comment: @SandeepBhandari I tried without it but it's still disappearing.

Comment: `scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated` should do the trick if you have implemented it correctly

Comment: @RijoPayyappilly Could you please elaborate on the correct implementation for it?

Answer (score 4):

Because you are using UIView.animate method, you have to put  self.view.layoutIfNeeded() after programmatically setting contentOffset

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4,
                   delay: 0.5, animations: {

                    self.headingsCollectionView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: x, y: 0)
                    self.headingsCollectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
```

Comment: I thought some dark magic it was. Thank you for clearing this out!